# Google datastudio - create charts like Google analytics does

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, looker-studio

I am currently working on a report for my websites in Google datastudio. Before using Datastudio I worked with Google analytics. The charts are really impressive and I wonder if I could rebuild a chart with those tab control in Datastudio. ('Nutzer' is a selectable button like 'Sitzungen' and so on).

[image: Google analytics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve **similar results** by combining Scorecards and [Optional Metrics](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9484925?hl=en).